# Change json format coming from api endpoint to use in component

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a basic react-native app which uses event data coming from a wordpress endpoint.

I have the json below coming from my wordpress api, how can I change the structure to fit into my calendar component which is below?

Where would be best to place to do this in my app? I dispatch an action in my app.js:

```
  eventsFetchData(
    "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events"
  )
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

My event reducer returns the state on success:

```
export function events(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'EVENTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
                return {
        ...action.events
      };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I `mapStateToProps` in my page component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        events: state.events,
    };
};
```

My json format needs to be this (startdate and title):

```
{{
                        "2012-05-08(startdate)": {
                            dots: [
                                {
                                    key: "vacation(title)",
                                    color: "blue",
                                    selectedDotColor: "white"
                                },
                                {
                                    key: "massage",
                                    color: "red",
                                    selectedDotColor: "white"
                                }
                            ],
                            selected: true
                        },
                        "2012-05-09": {
                            dots: [
                                {
                                    key: "vacation",
                                    color: "blue",
                                    selectedColor: "red"
                                },
                                {
                                    key: "massage",
                                    color: "red",
                                    selectedColor: "blue"
                                }
                            ],
                            disabled: true
                        }
                    }}
```

This is the data I have at the moment, I need to pull the `title` and `startdate` into the format above:

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "id":521,
         "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=521",
         "global_id_lineage":[
            "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=521"
         ],
         "author":"1",
         "status":"publish",
         "date":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
         "date_utc":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
         "modified":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
         "modified_utc":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
         "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/event\/lunchtime-lecture\/",
         "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/521",
         "title":"Lunchtime Lecture",
         "description":"<p>Mr Rehman<br \/>\nIschaemic Limb<\/p>",
         "excerpt":"",
         "image":false,
         "all_day":false,
         "start_date":"2018-01-02 09:30:00",
         "start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"02",
            "hour":"09",
            "minutes":"30",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "end_date":"2018-01-02 10:30:00",
         "end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"02",
            "hour":"10",
            "minutes":"30",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_start_date":"2018-01-02 09:30:00",
         "utc_start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"02",
            "hour":"09",
            "minutes":"30",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_end_date":"2018-01-02 10:30:00",
         "utc_end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"02",
            "hour":"10",
            "minutes":"30",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "timezone":"Europe\/London",
         "timezone_abbr":"GMT",
         "cost":"",
         "cost_details":{
            "currency_symbol":"",
            "currency_position":"prefix",
            "values":[

            ]
         },
         "website":"",
         "show_map":false,
         "show_map_link":false,
         "hide_from_listings":false,
         "sticky":false,
         "featured":false,
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"3rd Year - Firm 1",
               "slug":"3rd-year-firm-1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":59,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":2,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":59,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/59",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories"
               }
            }
         ],
         "tags":[

         ],
         "venue":{
            "id":523,
            "author":"1",
            "status":"publish",
            "date":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
            "date_utc":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
            "modified":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
            "modified_utc":"2017-12-14 12:23:56",
            "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/venue\/lecture-theatre\/",
            "venue":"Lecture Theatre",
            "show_map":true,
            "show_map_link":true,
            "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=523",
            "global_id_lineage":[
               "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=523"
            ]
         },
         "organizer":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "id":518,
         "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=518",
         "global_id_lineage":[
            "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=518"
         ],
         "author":"1",
         "status":"publish",
         "date":"2017-12-14 12:11:42",
         "date_utc":"2017-12-14 12:11:42",
         "modified":"2017-12-22 10:05:48",
         "modified_utc":"2017-12-22 10:05:48",
         "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/event\/another-one\/",
         "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/518",
         "title":"another one",
         "description":"",
         "excerpt":"",
         "image":false,
         "all_day":true,
         "start_date":"2018-01-31 00:00:00",
         "start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"31",
            "hour":"00",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "end_date":"2018-01-31 23:59:59",
         "end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"31",
            "hour":"23",
            "minutes":"59",
            "seconds":"59"
         },
         "utc_start_date":"2018-01-31 00:00:00",
         "utc_start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"31",
            "hour":"00",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_end_date":"2018-01-31 23:59:59",
         "utc_end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"01",
            "day":"31",
            "hour":"23",
            "minutes":"59",
            "seconds":"59"
         },
         "timezone":"Europe\/London",
         "timezone_abbr":"GMT",
         "cost":"",
         "cost_details":{
            "currency_symbol":"",
            "currency_position":"prefix",
            "values":[

            ]
         },
         "website":"",
         "show_map":true,
         "show_map_link":true,
         "hide_from_listings":false,
         "sticky":false,
         "featured":false,
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"3rd Year - Firm 1",
               "slug":"3rd-year-firm-1",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":59,
               "taxonomy":"tribe_events_cat",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":2,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":59,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories\/59",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/categories"
               }
            }
         ],
         "tags":[
            {
               "name":"calendarTwo",
               "slug":"calendartwo",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":58,
               "taxonomy":"post_tag",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":1,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":58,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/tags\/58",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/tags"
               }
            }
         ],
         "venue":[

         ],
         "organizer":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "id":516,
         "global_id":"wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=516",
         "global_id_lineage":[
            "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=516"
         ],
         "author":"2",
         "status":"publish",
         "date":"2017-12-14 12:00:37",
         "date_utc":"2017-12-14 12:00:37",
         "modified":"2017-12-22 10:05:28",
         "modified_utc":"2017-12-22 10:05:28",
         "url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/event\/test-event\/",
         "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/516",
         "title":"test event",
         "description":"<p>test event<\/p>",
         "excerpt":"",
         "image":false,
         "all_day":false,
         "start_date":"2018-02-14 08:00:00",
         "start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "end_date":"2018-04-24 17:00:00",
         "end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"04",
            "day":"24",
            "hour":"17",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_start_date":"2018-02-14 08:00:00",
         "utc_start_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"02",
            "day":"14",
            "hour":"08",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "utc_end_date":"2018-04-24 16:00:00",
         "utc_end_date_details":{
            "year":"2018",
            "month":"04",
            "day":"24",
            "hour":"16",
            "minutes":"00",
            "seconds":"00"
         },
         "timezone":"Europe\/London",
         "timezone_abbr":"GMT",
         "cost":"",
         "cost_details":{
            "currency_symbol":"",
            "currency_position":"prefix",
            "values":[

            ]
         },
         "website":"",
         "show_map":true,
         "show_map_link":true,
         "hide_from_listings":false,
         "sticky":false,
         "featured":false,
         "categories":[

         ],
         "tags":[
            {
               "name":"tester",
               "slug":"tester",
               "term_group":0,
               "term_taxonomy_id":57,
               "taxonomy":"post_tag",
               "description":"",
               "parent":0,
               "count":1,
               "filter":"raw",
               "id":57,
               "urls":{
                  "self":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/tags\/57",
                  "collection":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/tags"
               }
            }
         ],
         "venue":[

         ],
         "organizer":[

         ]
      }
   ],
   "rest_url":"http:\/\/wordpress.rguc.co.uk\/wp-json\/tribe\/events\/v1\/events\/?page=1&per_page=10&start_date=2017-12-28 23:59:00&end_date=2019-12-29 14:52:47",
   "total":"3",
   "total_pages":1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it's better to receive the information as it comes from the API and then store it in redux to accommodate your use case. Manipulating the actual response should be considered a no-no.

When you say `dispatch`, I assume you're using `redux`. If you're not, you may consider using it, as it will help in this very scenario. I would pass your `events` array through your `action` and map over it, storing the data you want in **an object map within the reducer**.

```
case FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED: {
  const events = { ...state.events };
  action.events.map(event => {
    const { year, month, day } = event.start_date_details;
    const startDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    events[startDate] = {
      dots: [
        {
          key: event.title,
          // add your fancy calendar styles
        }
      ],
      selected: true,
      disabled: false
    };
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    events
  };
}
```

I've formatted the above in the direction of your calendar component's required format but you may consider storing each `event` based on its `id`, including `startDate`, `endDate`, `title`, etc within each `event` object. Then, when you `connect` your calendar component, you can map over the `events` in `redux`, creating new object that is formatted specifically to that use case.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are from wordpress receiving has a lot of details in it, May i know what the "**key**" value you are looking in this huge data to be mapped as **dot object containing key, color and selectedColor**? To know where you can best do this, are you using redux to store the data fetched via word press end-point?

Now that we know what you are looking for, lets see some code below how we can achieve this. Here resultObj contains the output format.

```
// here is the code
// Assuming the data received from wordpress is stored in a object called wordpressObj. 
// we loop over the events array of this object, extract start date, then add all the dots dor this start date into this array.
var resultObj = {};
wordpressObj.events.map((eachObj) => {

   startDate = eachObj.start_date_details.year+"-"eachObj.start_date_details.month+"-"eachObj.start_date_details.day;

   if(!resultObj.hasOwnProperty(startDate))
   {
      resultObj.startDate.dots = [];
   }
   tempObj = {};
   tempObj.key = eachObj.title;
   tempObj.color = "blue";
   tempObj.selectedDotColor = "white";

   resultObj.startDate.dots.push(tempObj);

   //selected and deselected logic to come here , for now setting both of them as true
   resultObj.startDate.selected = true;
   resultObj.startDate.disabled = true;
});

console.log(resultObj);
```

Comment: I only need startdate and the title is key.

Comment: what about the second object in dots array, which has message as key value?

Comment: I think we are clubbing the data w.r.t. a data together here. Also on what basis do we show selected :true and disabled:false

Comment: Sorry, I need the title from each event object, in the dots array. When startdate or enddate matches the parent date, or the parent date is inbetween the startdate and enddate.

Comment: Okay, currently i have just matched the start date of the events